# Two Dimensional Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am creating a seating chart in java that displays the cost of each seat in a two dimensional array:

```
public class MovieTheater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int rows = 10;
        final int columns = 10; 
        int i;
        int j;
        int[][] seating = { 
            { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 },
            { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 },
            { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 },
            { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 }, 
            { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 },
            { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 }, 
            { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 }, 
            { 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20 },
            { 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 50, 40, 30, 30, 20 },
            { 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30 }
        };
```

However, when I attempt to print the array:

```
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.print(rows[i]);
            for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(columns[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive an error that states: **`array required, but int found`**

Is this a problem with my array format or a syntax problem for my print solution?

Comment: Please, be more specific in your question title. It'll help people in the web find more relevant results, and SO users as well.

Answer (score 1):

You do `columns[j]`, but `columns` is an `int`, so you can't access it like an array. Same with `rows[i]`. What you should do is in the inner loop

```
System.out.println(seating[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

"columns" and "rows" have been defined as int, not as arrays of type int. the index value of rows and columns can be used to access rows and columns of  array(seating). and it can be printed with a single print statement:

`for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
             for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) 
                System.out.print(seating[i][j]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually accessing your array object in your for loop.

Try this:

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(seating[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't work because you're trying to use an integer as an array.
In fact rows and columns are two integers (value 10); your array is `seating`.

When the compiler compiles your code it sees something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(10[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.print(10[j]);
    }
}
```

which is impossible.
What you really want is:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        System.out.print( seating[i][j] );
    }
}
```